# Return first date of year N in a column (Excel)

Tags: excel, date

I want to extract the first date of a given year from a column of dates (see below). E.g. I need a formula that would return 01.06.2015 if I ask for the first Date of the Year 2015 in column A.

Somehow I think this should be really simple but for the life of me I cant find a way to do it... Any and all help would be appreciated! 
Thx!

[My Excel Columne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e79X6.png)

Comment: Should this be done with a macro or with an excel formula?

Comment: with an excel formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(YEAR(A2:A16) = 2015,A2:A16))
```

being and array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or you can use this non CSE formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,A2:A16/(YEAR(A2:A16) = 2015),1)
```

In responce to your comment:

Aggregate is an array type formula.  One should not use full column references with array type formulas.  They will calculate every row.  So for each formula you are doing over 1 million calculations.  Instead use:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))/(YEAR(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))) = L22),1)
```

This will grow or contract the dataset to the actual data and not do any extra calculations.

Comment: this returns a value error (#VALUE!). likely because the "Value if true" returns the whole column A1:A16.

Comment: No, It returns value because your "dates" are not true dates but text that looks like dates.  You will need to change all your text that looks like dates to actual dates. @Grewi

Comment: sry, I think your non CSE formula might do the trick! Have to see if I can make it a bit more flexible but thank you very much already! I was starting to get a bit crazy here ;-)

Comment: Ah the issue with the first is that I included the Title row.  It needs to start at A2 not A1, My bad.  The 2nd ignores the error but the first does not.

Comment: The second works like a charm. I rewrote it to say [code]=AGGREGATE(15;6;A:A/(YEAR(A:A) = L22);1)[/code] so it is independend of the number of rows in column A. "L22" refers to a cell where the year I am looking for is written.

Comment: Aggregate is an array type formula.  One should not use full column references with array type formulas.  See edit for more information. @Grewi